# Modify calendar icon to close icon input type date react

Tags: html, reactjs, input, react-icons

[image]

Hi, I have been using useState inside react, when date is selected. But, if the date is empty or null I want to modify the calendar icon to close icon. when close icon is clicked it should clear the state.

const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState([null]);

```
<input className={CSS.dateSearch}
type="date"
value={selectedDate}
onChange={(e) => setSelectedDate(e.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: you can use inline if `selected ? 'yes' : 'no'`

Comment: Yeah but the problem is I cant able to change the icon using css

Comment: what calendar do you use? please share your code! no one is able to answer without code or demo

Comment: I have added the image on the top. In that there is a calendar icon. When a date is selected from the picker, the icon should be changed to a close icon and when a user clicks on close icon it should clear the date input

Comment: you should use inline if statement in your JSX codes. something like toggle